# Using multiple different input variables for supervised learning

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am familiar with the basics of machine learling in Python using scikit-learn. I would like to use multiple different variables to predict the rating of a hostel using supervised learning. The inputs that should be combined are

```
- The price of the room - a float.
- The comment of the travellers - a text transformed with a count vectorizer.
- The type of hostel - encoded as a categorical variable.
```

How can I feed all three input variables into the same algorithm (SVM is preferred). So the same comment "very nice place" would potentially be resulting in a different output based on whether the hostel is category 1 or 3 or whether room was 10 dollars a night or 25.

I now how to do it for each variable individually.

Comment: The straight forward approach would be to append these together, It might be problematic with the count vector, though. Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes, unfortunetaly that is more difficult in this set-up.

Comment: could you elaborate?

Comment: Not sure if I understood you correctly. But for example if it was two text variables "comment" and "hostel type" (small, medium, large) I would just add the strings as that each comment would begin with the respective hostel type (twice if bigrams are used for the count vectorizer).

Comment: What I meant is for you to do as in qaiser's answer, just append (`pd.concat` appends a data frame to a data frame) your feature dataframes together to get all of the features in 1 data frame, then you "feed" it to the SVM as is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

df = pd.DataFrame([['very high price',1000,'A',0],['location is not good',700,'B',0],['i will love to spend my next vaction in this hotel',1500,'B',1]], columns  =['comment','price','class','Rating'])

#creating dummy variable for category class
dummy_creat = pd.concat([df, pd.get_dummies(df['class'])], axis=1)


vect = CountVectorizer()
comment_feature = vect.fit_transform(dummy_creat['comment'])

text_feature_df = pd.DataFrame(comment_feature.todense(), columns = vect.get_feature_names())

final_feature_df = pd.concat([text_feature_df, dummy_creat[['price', 'A','B','Rating']]], axis=1)
```

this is going to be your input for training model which include both featrue of text as well as price and class

```
train_x = final_feature_df[final_feature_df.columns[:-1]]
train_y = final_feature_df['Rating']
```

And now when you want to do prediction for new comment

```
#use np.concat to merge other feature like price and class
new_value = np.concatenate((vect.transform(['damm it is of very high price']).todense(),[[900,0,1]]),1) # here 900 is price, 0 for class A and 1 for B 
model.predict(new_value)
```